# Create a cURL request using PATH API

Tags: php, curl

Guys. I am new to CURL so i have no experience on implementing CURL request. In this case, i want to post some data using CURL. Here is the CURL :

```
curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>' \
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
 -d '{"source_url": "http://url/to/photo.jpg", "caption": "I like cheese!"}' \
 https://partner.path.com/1/moment/photo
```

is there any of you guys know about implementing CURL request using the above data? Thank you very much.

Comment: Maybe you can be a little clearer? Do you want to implement that command line cURL request in PHP, and in some third party Path API ?

Comment: @adeneo : yes, that's what i want to do.

Answer (score 1):

finally, i found the answer. Here is how i create a request to the Path API

```
$url = 'https://partner.path.com/1/moment/photo';
$authorization = "Authorization: Bearer 8edf232243d58e4940d931490e882123432434f";
$headers = array($authorization,'Content-Type: application/json');
$json_data = '{"source_url": "http://url/to/photo.jpg", "caption": "I like cheese!"}';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r( $result );
```